# Outputting results of a foreach loop inside a div saved to a Session message

Tags: php

I have two pieces of this, and independently they both work perfectly, but I can't get the two combined, and it is making me crazy!  I am sure I am missing something basic.  I have a function that stores a Session message and displays it, operates just the way I want.

```
    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable text-center">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Sorry!</strong> Country abbreviation is in use by the following states:

        LIST OF STATES

        </div>');

    redirect($page);
```

Also, I have a foreach loop that generates the list of states:

```
        foreach($listresults as $listresult):
            echo $listresult['state_abbreviation'].', ';
        endforeach;
```

This also works ...  Now how do I get the results of the foreach loop to store where the LIST OF STATES is inside my session message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.
Let me guess thou.

```
foreach ($listresults as $lr):
    $stateList[] = $lr["state_abbreviation"];
endforeach;
keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable text-center">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Sorry!</strong> Country abbreviation is in use by the following states:

    ' . implode($stateList, ", ") . '

    </div>');
```

It prepares first list of states and stores them in `$stateList` variable.
Then we prepare normal message including imploded `$stateList`, so we can get rid of last ",".

Comment: You rock!!   Perfect!   I was sooooo close, I was sure I had to store it in a variable and then spit it back out, but just couldn't quite get there.